# Im getting this error while building react native app in windows

Tags: react-native

[image]

I was facing this error while building the react-native android app into the emulator
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I have installed jdk8 earliar I was having jdk 13. but then I downgraded to the lower version to jdk 8 and it worked.**